# How to separate pandas elements that contain lists

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a sample of the data.

```
data['nxt'].head()
​
Out[47]:
market_cap_by_available_supply  price_btc   price_usd   volume_usd
0   [1386136000000, 15091900]   [1386136000000, 1.3982e-05] [1386136000000, 0.0150919]  [1386136000000, 0.0]
1   [1386222394000, 14936300]   [1386222394000, 1.31922e-05]    [1386222394000, 0.0149363]  [1386222394000, 0.0]
2   [1386308781000, 11237100]   [1386308781000, 1.12001e-05]    [1386308781000, 0.0112371]  [1386308781000, 0.0]
3   [1386395502000, 7031430]    [1386395502000, 9.6644e-06] [1386395502000, 0.00703143] [1386395502000, 0.0]
4   [1386481920000, 6292640]    [1386481920000, 8.82299e-06]    [1386481920000, 0.00629264] [1386481920000, 0.0]
```

I'm only interested in:`market_cap_by_available_supply`

```
data['nxt'].market_cap_by_available_supply

0      [1386136000000, 15091900]
1      [1386222394000, 14936300]
2      [1386308781000, 11237100]
3       [1386395502000, 7031430]
4       [1386481920000, 6292640]
```

The purpose for this post is: How can we seperate these into two columns: Timestamp and Marketcap ?

But my ultimate goal here is (using code below)

Create a new Dataframe containing marketcaps and timestamps for dashcoin, then sequentially add the other coin's marketcaps that correspond to DASH's timestamp, any help with this would be great.

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd

coins = ['dashcoin','litecoin','dogecoin','nxt']

API = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/datapoints/'

data = {}

for coin in coins: 
    data[coin]=(pd.read_json(API + coin))

MC_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=[['Timestamp']+coins])
```

EDIT:

I'm using for loops as later I will be adding many'coins'. @timmy, your method for extracting the timestamp and cap worked great, although i can't get the merge method to work.

```
data2 = {}

for coin in coins:
    #seperates timestamp and marketcap from their respective list inside each element
    TS = data[coin].market_cap_by_available_supply.map(lambda r: r[0])
    cap = data[coin].market_cap_by_available_supply.map(lambda r: r[1])
    #Creates DataFrame and stores timestamp and marketcap data into dictionairy
    df = DataFrame(columns=['timestamp','cap'])
    df.timestamp = TS
    df.cap = cap
    data2[coin] = df

for coin in coins: 

data2['merged'] = data2['merged'].merge(data[coin], on='timestamp', how='outer')


KeyError: 'merged'
```

Comment: I updated my answer to solve your most recent problem. The problem comes from the fact that you're trying to merge the first coin dataframe with nothing (nothing in `data2['merged']` on the first iteration in the loop)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, you can use the map function:

```
# Just renaming for readability
cap_by_supply = data['nxt']['market_cap_by_available_supply']

# Exploding the market_cap_by_available_supply array into 2 columns
data['nxt']['timestamp'] = cap_by_supply.map(lambda r: r[0])
data['nxt']['cap'] = cap_by_supply.map(lambda r: r[1])
```

Regarding your second question, if I understood well:
You can create a dataframe for each coin type. They should be all formatted the same way, with a `timestamp` column and a `cap` column. Then use the [merge function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge them through the timestamp column. You definitely want to remove all the columns that you don't want to merge, for example:

```
# Drop unwanted columns, to repeat for each coin dataframe.
# Here we keep timestamp and cap only, for example.
data['nxt'] = data['nxt'].drop([
    'market_cap_by_available_supply',
    'price_btc',
    'price_usd',
    'volume_usd'
], axis=1)

# Merge all the coin frames into one
data['coins'] = data['dashcoin'].merge(data['litecoin'], on='timestamp', how='outer')
data['coins'] = data['coins'].merge(data['dogecoin'], on='timestamp', how='outer')
data['coins'] = data['coins'].merge(data['nxt'], on='timestamp', how='outer')
```

You want to specify `outer` join so that you keep all your records.

Hope it helps, I'm taking remarks and advices if anyone understood better or has a better solution.

---

**EDIT** regarding OP's EDIT:

On the first iteration of your loop, there's nothing in `data2['merged']` and you can't merge a dataframe with nothing. We just need to say that `data2['merged']` is, at first, just a copy of the first coin dataframe. Then we loop over `coins` starting from the second dataframe, because the first one is already in `data2['merged']`

```
...

data2['merged'] = data2[coins[0]]
for coin in coins[1:]: 
    data2['merged'] = data2['merged'].merge(data2[coin], on='timestamp', how='outer')
```

Comment: This is great man thanks, I never would have figured out how to do the first part, i wonder if there is a simpler way. Either way I need to research lamba. 

I'm just attempting the second part

Comment: Hmm, can't get the merge method to work, comments in my edit

Comment: @Dave990 I added a bit of code in my answer regarding your edit.